# Ubuntu Lockups - Ubuntu 23.10 Fresh Install

Tags: nvidia, freeze, 23.10, lockup

I am getting frequent lockups on Ubuntu 23.10. It's a fresh install. I have done extensive hardware testing and found no problems. No lockups on Windows when I run it (but would rather run Ubuntu). BIOS is up to date on the PC. I have reported this as a bug. I don't know if there is anything else I can do. [Bug 2054121] Re: Random Freezing
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/2054121